# How can I learn the details of an engine that's not original?

Tags: chevrolet, manual-transmission

I've got an 86 Chevy C10 pickup.  The engine has been replaced with what I have been told is a "354".  Most of the work I've done on cars has been via a Haynes manuel.  But, because I'm dealing with a different engine, I don't know where to find information on torque specs, how to's etc.

I'm not a pro, but I have decent tools and some experience.  I know a mechanic who can help me through the tough parts, but I want to be able to do some of the more basic stuff on my own.  Can I buy a hayne's for this type of engine, if yes how do I figure out which one to buy?  Or, what else can I do?

**UPDATE**
I found the numbers "14101074" stamped in the back center of the engine, just behind the carburetor.  According to several online sources this engine casting number is for a 305 engine belonging to an 82-92 Camaro.  Considering it has TPI,that puts it between 87 - 92.

Comment: You sure they didn't mean 454? Do you know if it's a smallblock or bigblock?

Comment: I don't know if it's smallblock or bigblock or how to tell.  I believe the original engine was a 454, but this engine is definitely smaller.  Two guys better than I said it was a 354.

Comment: I'd be good with a 355, or a 454. Don't think I have ever heard of a 354. Based on [this thread](http://forums.luvtruck.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=6760) however it may indeed be a 354

Comment: @MarkJohnson - Well there is, but that's original equipment info.  This is a different engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can figure out another application (vehicle) for that engine, you can refer to the engine related parts of a manual for that application.  Or at least look up information on the internet.

There will be numbers cast into the block which should help identify it.  Here's a [link](http://www.chevyasylum.com/tech/decode.html) to get you started, assuming you've got a small block Chevy.  [This](http://www.castingnumbers.info/site/main) looks like a nice database once you've got the numbers.

Comment: I havent found those numbers yet.  Can I see these numbers with the engine still in the truck?

Answer (score 4):

there is typically a casting number on the block. It is located just to the rear of the drivers side cylinder head. Don't confuse this with the serial number pad that is located on the front of the block in front of the passenger side cylinder head. [This site](http://www.chevyasylum.com/tech/decode.html) has some good photos showing both locations.

Comment: Did you forgot the link?